# Two Resident permits in Schengen without taxes

Tags: resident-permit

I am from India working in Czech Republic with an EU Blue card with Czech Republic Address. Moreover my wife is a permanent resident of Germany. Can I keep the Blue card (Residence permit) in Czech and also get a residence permit in Germany also (as a dependent of my wife)?

Comment: What's your goal here? Where would you be residing? Working? And what's your concern with taxes? You could probably apply for a residence permit in Germany without immediately losing your Blue Card but it will be difficult to maintain both long-term and wouldn't necessarily achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also: how long have you been residing in the Czech Republic on the Blue Card?

Comment: As @Relaxed's questions imply, the options available to you depend on where you intend to reside and perhaps on whether you intend to commute regularly between Germany and the Czech Republic.  What is your intention?